# Issue with editor highlighting in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, highlighting

I have an issue after switching to running Ubuntu when developing instead of Windows.

When I ran Eclipse in Windows, I could find the software market thing and get good and easy-to-use color themes from there to install. Since I couldn't find anything of this on my Ubuntu version, I decided to edit it all manually.

Here is my issue: I was able to adjust the color of the 'mark occurrences'-function that highlights all the all the places where a code piece occurs, but my program does something else to the place where variables are first declared. I took a simple screen shot that displays the problem:
http://www.freeimagehosting.net/19e90

When I disable 'mark occurrences', the super-bright highlighting on variable declarations do not go away, so it's not part of the same setting. I also can't find where I change the color of this, because it's quite annoying not to be able to read what's written due to the coloring of that highlight.

Do you know how I can disable this extra-marking of declarations? Or at least change the color of it? I can't find anything when googling it, but maybe I'm just searching for the wrong things.

Thanks in advance and sorry for this very long post!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend installing a new version of Eclipse on Ubuntu.

I'm developing on Kubuntu and have no issues.  Make sure you delete all previous settings before reinstalling.  Default settings should have them enabled.